# pyspark how to split up data into smaller bits

Tags: python-2.7, apache-spark, parallel-processing, pyspark, memory-efficient

My computation creates a massive amount of bloat; my calculation progresses like this:

1. RDD entries are single items
2. I create permutations of those entries for values.  This creates a large amount of bloat
3. `.flatMap` on those values.  There are at least 1000 *times* more entries now than there were at the start
4. `groupByKey` to get fewer entries than at the start

Somewhere in step 3 and/or 4 I get memory errors.  I have created massive clusters; way too big, and still get memory errors.

How do I split up my data into smaller chunks so that my worker nodes don't get overloaded with the bloat?

*edit*
Here is what my code looks like:

```
rdd_processed = (
  rdd_source_data
  .map(lambda x: (x, creates_big_list(x)))  # value is ~1000 entries large
  .flatMap(lambda t: t)
  .groupByKey()
  .mapValues(list)
)
```

*edit 2*:

Partitioned the original rdd and updated grouping function (thanks for the tip):

```
rdd_processed = (
  rdd_source_data
  .partitionBy(10000)
  .map(lambda x: (x, creates_big_list(x)))  # value is ~1000 entries large
  .flatMap(lambda t: (t[0], [t[1]]))
  .reduceByKey(lambda x, y: x+y)
)
```

seemed to have helped, but not enough.

I've played around with the size of the `partitionBy`, though I can't seem to get it to not overflow my memory.  Am I using it right?

Comment: Well, `.groupByKey().mapValues(list)` makes things pretty much as bad as it is possible.  It would make more sense to use generators in `.map(lambda x: (x, creates_big_list(x)))`. The rest depends on how you use `rdd_processed`.

Comment: @zero323, am I using `partitionBy` correctly?  Should I `coalesce` afterwards again?  I end up combining this rdd with a few others with `sc.union([list of rdds])`, and then reducing again.  That is where my memory error seems to have shifted to

Comment: Controlling number of partitions is a good idea but   .`flatMap(lambda t: (t[0], [t[1]])).reduceByKey(lambda x, y: x+y)` is a really bad one. I explained [somewhere else](https://github.com/awesome-spark/spark-gotchas/blob/master/04_rdd_actions_and_transformations_by_example.md#how-not-to-optimize) why you shouldn't group by key this way. Regarding coalesce you should basically react to the expect change in size. If you end up mostly with empty or small partitions then reducing is a good idea.